# How to troubleshoot hdparm?

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, nas, spindown

I'm setting up a NAS, and I would like the HDs to spin down when I am not doing anything (i.e., most of the time), but I am having trouble realising this with hdparm.

I can spin down the HDs manually, using `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sd[a-b]`
They will restart automatically when I access the HDs via the netwerk, but even when I don't do this, they restart soon (within a minute?).

When I try to have them spin down automatically using `sudo hdparm -S 1 /dev/sd[a-b]`, nothing seems to happen (they will stay spinning).

How can I find out what is keeping my HDs spinning, or what else is going wrong? I'd like to keep the NAS running, so I can access the HDs over the network without manually booting the NAS. But I would also like to save the HDs from running permanently, wearing out too soon and costing unnecessary energy.

If `hdparm` is not the state-of-the-art way to do this, please let me know as well.

Lots of thanks in advance!

Short description of my system:
QNAP TS-253D containing two HDs (WDC WD40EFAX-68JH4N0) mirrored using zpool
with Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS running on an external SSD, connected via USB

In response to the comment by mikewhatever; when I execute `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda` I cannot find `Power Managment` plus a number in the output:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -C5 -i Power
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
--
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
           *    NCQ priority information
           *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
           *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                Device-initiated interface power management
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
```

Comment: Run `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdX`, whatever it is (/dev/sdb, dev/sdc, etc), and look for "Power Managment". The defalt value is usually 254, if so, set it to 128 or less.

Comment: Why did you dump the output into the comment section? Why not add it to the question?

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks, and hope this gives a clue to my issue

Comment: I wouldn't bet on being powered on wearing out the drives. Spinning up is a bigger stress...

Comment: Ah, much better now. I get a similar output from an SSD. Have you tried it on a mechanical disk, aka HDD?

Comment: I do think this is my HDD, the output of "hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -i model" gives "Model Number: WDC WD40EFAX-68JH4N0"

Comment: Maybe spindown should not be my goal, but why do the HDDs keep rattling, even when I did not 'ask' for any activity?